# Sed from line 6 on from all txt files and being able to output all the results in a single file

Tags: sed, grep

I need to sed from all *.txt files from line 6 until the end 
All the results should be in a new single file with the name of each file preceding the results

Example:
Having different txt files
the result should be one single that looks like this taking from the 3rd line to the end

```
file 1
3
4
5
file 2
3
4
5
file 3
3
4
5
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us i) your input files and ii) your desired output. Showing ambiguous output (should the file names be in the output or not?) and no input is not very helpful since we can't help get you from here to there unless we know what _here_ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -s '1F;6,$!d' -- *.txt > output
```

Portably, you could use `awk` instead:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {print FILENAME}; FNR>=6' ./*.txt > output
```

(note that in both cases, hidden files are excluded).

Empty files won't be referenced, but files that have fewer than 6 lines will. If you don't want to hear about those, you can do:

```
sed -s '6F;6,$!d' -- *.txt > output
awk 'FNR == 6 {print FILENAME}; FNR>=6' ./*.txt > output
```

Or if you want to see all files:

```
for f in *.txt; do
  printf '%s\n' "$f"
  tail -n +6 < "$f"
done > output
```

With GNU `tail`, you also do:

```
$ tail -vn +6 -- *.txt
==> a.txt <==
6
7
8
9
10

==> b.txt <==
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect
I will be using awk

is there an edit to this function to make my file look as follow
original file:
'file 1
1
2
3
4
5
Done'

file needed 
'file 1
3
4
5

file 2
3
4
5
6'

while having an empty line in between
and while removing the last line which is "done"

Comment: @Chris, I'd suggest asking a separate question for that.